# Is $F$ greater than the axial component of $f$?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, flow

It is assumed that the flow at the convergent nozzle outlet is constant. f is the force exerted by the convergent nozzle shell on the fluid in the nozzle. F is the axial force of upstream fluid to the fluid in the nozzle. Is F greater than the axial component of f? I think F greater than the axial component of f. Therefore, the convergent nozzle will generate recoil force.
Is my idea correct?

[image: convergent nozzle]

Comment: It's possible to use integral balance equations to do things in the right way. An answer will follow...

Comment: See the answer below. I'm not downvoting, and I'm asking why someone has downvoted without at least leaving a comment. This behavior always drives me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the force acting on the solid body due to the convergent flow, you need to carefully used the integral balances.

It's possible to study the system using integral balances of the mass and the momentum of the steady control volume coinciding with the internal volume of the nozzle, delimited by the inflow and outflow surfaces, assuming steady condition $\frac{d}{dt} \equiv 0$, and negligible volume forces $\mathbf{g} \equiv 0$,

- mass:

  $\displaystyle \underbrace{\dfrac{d}{dt} \int_V \rho}_{=0} + \oint_{\partial V} \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0$
- momentum:

  $\displaystyle \underbrace{\dfrac{d}{dt} \int_V \rho \mathbf{u}}_{=\mathbf{0}} + \oint_{\partial V} \rho \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \underbrace{\int_V \rho \mathbf{g}}_{=\mathbf{0}} + \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{t_n}$.

Assuming uniform velocity on the inflow and outflow surfaces, assuming negligible viscous forces on the inflow and outflow surfaces it's possible to write

- mass: $\rho_1 U_1 A_1 = \rho_2 U_2 A_2 = \dot{m}$
- momentum, in the axial direction:
  $\rho_2 U_2^2 A_2 - \rho_1 U_1^2 A_1 = P_1 A_1 - P_2 A_2 + F_{fs,x}$, or, if we foresee that the solid exerts on the fluid a force pointing on the left and we don't like negative unknowns, we can define $F_{fs,x}^{to\ the\ left} = - F_{fs,x}$

  $\rho_2 U_2^2 A_2 - \rho_1 U_1^2 A_1 = P_1 A_1 - P_2 A_2 - F_{fs,x}^{to\ the\ left}$

  being $F_{fs,x}$ the force applied on the fluid by the solid wall.

Now, we can recast  the momentum equation as

$\dot{m}(U_2 - U_1) = P_1 A_1 - P_2 A_2 - F_{fs,x}^{to\ the\ left}$,

and since $U_2 > U_1$ we can conclude that

$0 \lt \dot{m}(U_2 - U_1) = P_1 A_1 - P_2 A_2 - F_{fs,x}^{to\ the\ left}$ and thus

$ P_1 A_1 > P_2 A_2 + F_{fs,x}^{to\ the\ left} $.

Concluding, $P_1 A_1$ is not only larger than $F_{fs,x}^{to\ the\ left} $, but also of the sum of the wall force and the resultant of stress on the outflow surface.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. Because F is greater than the axial component of f, there will be a pure force F1 pointing to the right, and the reaction force of F1 is the recoil force. Of course, F is finally applied by upstream fluid or water pump. This is similar to the principle of guns. Therefore, the convergent nozzle will generate recoil force. However, some people do not agree with this conclusion. They believe that the recoil force is caused by hose bending.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't care about what people think. I trust in Math and Physics much more than people, self-defined degree-certified scientists included

Comment: Do you agree that the recoil force of convergent nozzle is caused by the reason I mentioned?